# Weighted quiver in Keller's Java Quiver mutation

Tags: cluster-algebras

I need to do mutation using weighted quivers. There are weights on the arrows which looks like: [image]

How to draw weighted quiver in Keller's Java Quiver mutation: 
https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~bernhard.keller/quivermutation/?

Thank you very much.